# monitor real memory usage in linux using perl and snmp

Tags: linux, perl, memory

I need to get the real free memory in an stripped Linux appliance. I want to get real free memory.
Getting the free memory does not take into account the buffers/cache so I seems to be out of ram while I still have plenty left for applications.

I am using snmp to get this value from a Perl script, and I have these oid at my disposal:

```
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.1 = STRING: Physical memory 
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.3 = STRING: Virtual memory
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.6 = STRING: Memory buffers
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.7 = STRING: Cached memory
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.10 = STRING: Swap space
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.31 = STRING: /
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.32 = STRING: /boot
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.33 = STRING: /var/log
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.1 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.3 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.6 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.7 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.10 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.31 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.32 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.33 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 8240104
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.3 = INTEGER: 16626024
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.6 = INTEGER: 8240104
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.7 = INTEGER: 4697308
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.10 = INTEGER: 8385920
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.31 = INTEGER: 4062954
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.32 = INTEGER: 295561
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.33 = INTEGER: 33011530
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.1 = INTEGER: 5610512
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.3 = INTEGER: 5610512
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.6 = INTEGER: 326360
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.7 = INTEGER: 4697308
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.10 = INTEGER: 0
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.31 = INTEGER: 1673253
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.32 = INTEGER: 24061
> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.33 = INTEGER: 19467049
```

I do not manage to get what is my exact RAM usage in Linux I have to add the the physical free memory what is stored in the cache and buffers?
What is the best way to do it in Perl? Is the hrStorage the best or is best to use de UCD-SNMP_MIB (.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4)?

edit: I created the following scriptlet that would based on comments here calculate the real used memory percent. Do you think is the best I can do or is there anything else I should do?

```
my $memRealTotalOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0';
my $memRealFreeOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0';
my $memRealCachedOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0';
my $memRealBuffersOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0';

my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
     -hostname  => $np->opts->host,
     -community => $np->opts->community,
   );

   if (!defined $session) {
      $np->nagios_exit (WARNING, $error)
      #printf "ERROR: %s.\n", $error;
   }

   my $memRealFree = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $memRealFreeOID],);
   my $memRealTotal = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $memRealTotalOID],);
   my $memRealCached = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $memRealCachedOID],);
   my $memRealBuffers = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $memRealBuffersOID],);

$session->close();

   my $buffers = $memRealBuffers->{$memRealBuffersOID}; 
   my $cache = $memRealCached->{$memRealCachedOID};
   my $total=  $memRealTotal->{$memRealTotalOID};
   my $free = $memRealFree->{$memRealFreeOID};

   my $memRealUsed = $total - $free;
   my $memRealUsedMB = round ($memRealUsed / 1024);
   my $totalMB = round($total / 1024);


  my $realTPercent = (($memRealUsed - $buffers - $cache)/ $total) * 100;
  my $realPercent = sprintf "%.2f", $realTPercent;
```

Comment: Memory in cache and buffers is in use to hold data that you might want.  It is not free.  Ideally, free should always be close to 0.

Comment: @stark Not true: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: I based my assumptions in that website exactly.. www.linuxatemyram.com

Comment: Please try running a loop that drops all of your buffers and cache every 10 seconds and see what happens to your performance.  Then come back and tell me how that memory was "free".

Comment: Re. your edit: If all you want is total free memory (roughly), you can just add `memAvailReal.0 + memBuffer.0 + memCached.0`. No need to do `memTotalReal.0 - memAvailReal.0`. I think this is the best you're gonna get with SNMP without doing something like [this](https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/mrtg/2005-December/031051.html). Also, it looks like you're using Nagios; you might check if there's an existing plugin to do this.

Answer (score 4):

`hrStorageUsed` includes buffers and cache, so you can get an estimate of total free RAM like this:

```
totFree = total - used + buffers + cache
```

For example, with the following values:

```
$ snmpwalk -Os -v1 -cpublic localhost hrStorage | grep '\.[167] ='
hrStorageIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
hrStorageIndex.6 = INTEGER: 6
hrStorageIndex.7 = INTEGER: 7
hrStorageType.1 = OID: hrStorageRam  
hrStorageType.6 = OID: hrStorageOther
hrStorageType.7 = OID: hrStorageOther
hrStorageDescr.1 = STRING: Physical memory
hrStorageDescr.6 = STRING: Memory buffers
hrStorageDescr.7 = STRING: Cached memory
hrStorageAllocationUnits.1 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
hrStorageAllocationUnits.6 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
hrStorageAllocationUnits.7 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 1016436
hrStorageSize.6 = INTEGER: 1016436
hrStorageSize.7 = INTEGER: 436156
hrStorageUsed.1 = INTEGER: 882112
hrStorageUsed.6 = INTEGER: 103056
hrStorageUsed.7 = INTEGER: 436156
```

We have:

```
totFree = hrStorageSize.1 - hrStorageUsed.1 + hrStorageUsed.6 + hrStorageUsed.7
        = 1016436         - 882112          + 103056          + 436156
        = 673536 KB
```

---

But wait, that's not what `free(1)` says:

```
$ free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1016436      235480      135680       51272      645276      555492
Swap:       1048572      113076      935496
```

According to this, we actually have:

```
totFree = free   + buff/cache
        = 135680 + 645276
        = 780956 KB
```

Why the discrepancy? As it turns out, both `free` and HOST-RESOURCES-MIB get their data from `/proc/meminfo`, but use slightly different metrics. From `man free`:

> **buffers**
>
> Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)
>
> **cache**
>
> Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and Slab in /proc/meminfo)

So `free` includes slab allocation in cache, while HOST-RESOURCES-MIB doesn't. If we get the slab allocation:

```
$ grep Slab /proc/meminfo
Slab:             106064 kB
```

and add it to what we got from SNMP, we have:

```
totFree = 673536 + 106064
        = 779600 KB
```

which is much closer to what we got from `free` (780956 KB).

---

However, there's actually a better metric for this. Again from `man free`:

> **available**
>
> Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache or free fields, this field  takes  into  account  page  cache  and  also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)

Note that in my example, the available memory (555492 KB) is significantly lower than the total of free + buffers + cache (780956 KB).

Unfortunately, I can't find a MIB that reports this value (UCD-SNMP-MIB doesn't either), so you may be stuck with the rough estimate I showed at the beginning.